# Encoding issue, where to put 'ignore'?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working in Python 3.7 and I should write a code that iterates through all of the files in the folder. However some of the files have different encoding and I would like to ignore the `"UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1637` error. I managed to put argument `errors='ignore'` into other pieces of code and it works fine. However I do not know where to insert it into this piece of code:

```
import glob, os, fileinput
from glob import glob
root_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(root_dir)
for filename in glob('*.txt'):
with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True) as file:
            for line in file: 
            print(line.replace('| |', '|'), end='')
```

Thank you!

Comment: maybe it's an exception? try: (...) catch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was bypassed by specifying the mode.

```
with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True,mode='r') as file:
```

The whole code.

```
import glob, os, fileinput
from glob import glob
root_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(root_dir)
for filename in glob('*.txt'):
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True,mode='r') as file:
        for line in file:
                print(line.replace('| |', '|'), end='')
```